# Whats Master Chief's real name

Tags: halo-series

I have only heard Cortana say "chief" That is all I Heard and I've tried looking it up, but I found nothing

Answer (score 6):

Master Chief's real name is John. Nobody really knows his what his last name was as when we was "acquired" for the Spartan II program he was simply John-117.

You can read more about John's backstory by reading *The Fall of Reach*(a better choice) or by reading the Wiki [here](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/John-117)(a quicker choice)

Answer (score 3):

His first name is John. His last name is unknown (he was abducted by ONI when he was 6). His designation in training was John-117, and throughout the Covenant War before the events of Reach he was just  Spartan-117 or Master Chief.